# How to make jar available for Maven usage?

Tags: maven

I would like developers to be able to use my jar as a maven dependency, but am confused as to where to start.  Is there some sort of metadata file I need to include to indicate version information and such?

Comment: Start from ["maven-in-five-minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)

Comment: and then https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html

Comment: but these are guides to how I can setup my maven repository.  I just want to provide my jar for maven usage, is there anything required other than just the jar?

Comment: how did you generate the Jar? is it using Maven already? If yes, no need. Just provide them the repo location, and the artifact details. If not, these guides will tell you what you need to do.

Comment: @pyStarter The question is reasonably clear. Being a beginner's question, there could be duplicates, but I wasn't able to find one here on SO.

Comment: @user3299059 Which developers shall be able to use your JAR? Just people within your organization or everyone on the web?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Answer (score 0):

Just a E.g. If i need to use xyz.jar in my local system then

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.x.y.z</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>C:\myjars\xyz.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of sharing your artifact within a group of people, that's what you need to consider:

1. your artifact is advised to be built with POM generated.  Most straight forward way is to use Maven as the build tools and POM is simply the project definition.  Gradle also capable in generating a POM for your final artifact.
2. Now your artifact is "capable" to be used in Maven.  However, other developers have no clue on how to get your artifact.  You should consider setting up an inhouse Maven repository, and publish your artifact to that repository (In Maven, we call it "deploy").  Other developers can set in their settings to make use of that inhouse repository and download artifact from it.  Most commonly used repository includes Nexus and Artifactory.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to publish your JAR is to upload it to Maven Central. This is the repository which is pre-configured in Maven, so your JAR will be usable by all Maven projects without any additional configuration.

You will need to create a Maven pom.xml file for your JAR which defines ID and version of your artifact. This and all further steps are explained in the detailed guide here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html